# Dynamic table size with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to generate a table dynamically while setting the rows and columns as variables once. My loop looks like this

```
var tr = 4
var td = 4

for (var r = 0; r < tr; r++ ) {
  $('<tr id=' + r + '>/<tr>').appendTo('table');
    for (var c = 0; c < td; c++){
      $('<td></td>').appendTo('#' + r);
    }
}
```

tr would be the number of rows and td would be the number of columns.  The result is 8 rows and 4 columns seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/f637V/1/

What is wrong with my loop?

Comment: If you right click and inspect the table, you'll see 8 rows.

Comment: Ah. Typo, should be `</tr>`, not `/<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$('<tr id=' + r + '>/<tr>').appendTo('table');
```

To

```
$('<tr id=' + r + '></tr>').appendTo('table');
```

Comment: Don't forget to flag to close the question.